# Redirect after login yii2

Tags: yii2

How to change url after login from `/week/backend/web/` to `google.com` for example? I have this in .htaccess

```
`AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
RewriteRule ^admin(\/?.*)$ backend/web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
RewriteRule ^(\/?.*)$ backend/web/$1 [L]`
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect user that has just signed in to `google.com`?

Comment: @Bizley google is just for example

Comment: Sure, my question was not about details but rather idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `backend` in your example so I assume it's based on advanced application template.

Replace [this line in SiteController](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/backend/controllers/SiteController.php#L79):

```
return $this->goBack();
```

with

```
return $this->redirect('http://google.com');
```

You don't have to wrap URL in `Url::to()` there.

Redirect happens if user successfully logs in.